# JSON Schema: using property value defined in another object

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have two properties in JSON Schema:
`"A": {"type": "object", "properties":{ "X":{"type":"boolean"}}}`
`"B": {"type": "object", "properties":{...}}`

In the logic of `B` I need to use value of `X` to set `B` property values and `"required":[...]`.
How do I use value of `X` within the `B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a rule at the schema level that defines the object that contains these two properties. You can then use the `dependentSchemas`, `dependentRequired`, or `if`/`then`/`else` keywords to define rules like "if <something> in property A, then <something> in property B".

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

For example:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties":{ "X":{"type":"boolean"}}
    },
    "B": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties":{...}
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "required": ["A"],
    "properties": {
      "A": {
        "required": ["X"],
        "properties": { "X": { "const": true } }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": ["B"],
    "properties": {
      "B": {
        "required": ["Y"],
        "properties": { "Y": { "const": "/A/X is true" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is saying "if property A exists, and has a subproperty X which is true, then there must be a property Y under B which is the string "/A/X is true"".

Comment: Thank your for the response. `You need to declare a rule at the schema level that defines the object that contains these two properties.`  -- I'm not exactly following you here.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about the standard specification of JSON Schema in general, you can't "use" values from the JSON instance at some other place for validation in the meaning that, for example, you take a value and fill a `required` keyword with it.

However, you can define conditions using `if-then-else` that use values to decide what other schemas should be applied subsequently at this point in the validation flow.

The `dependentSchemas` and `dependentRequired` keywords are focused on the presence of properties.

More details are available [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html).